# What is wrong with Canvas.SetTop(element,position)

Tags: wpf, canvas, mouse, controls, move

I am trying to move and reposition elements with mouse and through code. But I guess I'm missing something or do something the wrong way. So I built a little sample app. It's just a empty wpf app with this MainWindow function

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label lText = new Label();
        lText.Content = "this is my test label";
        lText.Height = 50;
        lText.Width = 50;
        lText.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
        // do I really need to do this? 
        lText.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        lText.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        // this part already fails
        Canvas.SetTop(lText, 20);
        Canvas.SetLeft(lText, 10);
        this.Content = lText;
    }
```

Comment: @Clemens: Why a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the Left and Top properties must be set inside the Xaml before you can read it. I was always getting NaN and therefor couldn't set the correct value either.

Answer (score 2):

The attached properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` (which in code behind are set by the `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop` methods) only have an effect for an element that is a direct child of a Canvas control.

So declare a Canvas as Content element in your MainWindow's XAML:

```
<Window ...>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" />
</Window>
```

Then add the element to the Canvas' `Children` collection in code behind:

```
Canvas.SetTop(lText, 20);
Canvas.SetLeft(lText, 10);
canvas.Children.Add(lText);
```

Comment: Okay - Understood. How can I move a control without being a child of canvas. I mean if I have no canvas at all like in my example.

Comment: If you have no Canvas, add one to your XAML. There are of course other ways to position an element, like setting its `Margin` or `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTransform`, but Canvas is the typical way to do it.